# Average height of a point based on nearby points

Tags: math, height, average, weighted, elevation

I have a situation in my game. I am experimenting with terrain generation.

I have a bunch of peaks, whose position and elevation i know.
I have a point which is surrounded by all these peaks. I know its position. I am trying to calculate the elevation of this point.

I would like to calculate the height of this point, based on how close/far it is to each of these peaks, and the elevation of each of these peaks.

Example:
Peak 1 is at (0,0), with an elevation of 500
Peak 2 is at (100,100), with an elevation of 1000
Peak 3 is at (0,100), with an elevation of 750

If my point is at (99,99), i want the elevation of this point to be as close to 1000.

What is the name of this problem? 
If you already have a solution to this, that too will be much appreciated.

**Note**: In addition, it will be helpful if the formula/equation also allows me to generate negative elevations. for example, a point midway between all the peaks could as well be under sea level. Any formula i can menatally think of usually gives me just positive results. I assume some kind of 'Slope' must be considered to allow this.

One equation i though of so far is                                                                                
`P1.height * (Sum of all distances - distance from P1)/(Sum of all distances) +
P2.height * (Sum of all distances - distance from P2)/(Sum of all distances) +
...                                                                                                                                                                     Pn.height * (Sum of all distances - distance from Pn)/(Sum of all distances)`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To draw the peaks your game needs to convert the coordinates of the peaks to screen coordinates.
Such calculation is usually done by multiplying a matrix with the vector containing the coordinates (in java AWT such matrix would be called a transform).
What you need is the inverse of that matrix so that you can apply it to your screen coordinates.
So the solution is:

- get the matrix that is used for rendering the terrain
- calculate the inverse matrix
- apply it to your screen coordinates

And it might even be more efficient not to use the original matrix to calculate the inverse matrix but use the parameters (zero point, scale factors and rotation angle) which were used to calculate the original matrix. The same parameters can be used to calculate the inverse matrix.